# doCrypto method for asymetric key (RSA)

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm implementing rsa and aes classes in java, but i have some trouble with the rsa implementation.
Since i have two keys in asymetric encryption, with two different types, i've made two differents methods, one for each. Is there a better/cleaner way to do that?

```
private static byte[] doCrypto(
        int cipherMode,
        PublicKey publicKey,
        byte[] inputBytes)
        throws CryptoException {
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] outputBytes;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(cipherMode, publicKey);
        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | InvalidKeyException
            | BadPaddingException
            | IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        throw new CryptoException("Error doCrypto", ex);
    }
    return outputBytes;
}

private static byte[] doCrypto(
        int cipherMode,
        PrivateKey privateKey,
        byte[] inputBytes)
        throws CryptoException {
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] outputBytes;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(cipherMode, privateKey);
        outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | InvalidKeyException
            | BadPaddingException
            | IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        throw new CryptoException("Error doCrypto", ex);
    }
    return outputBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the two different methods for the encrypt/decrypt, yes, you can reduce them to just one function. The `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` classes both extend the `Key` interface, and that's what's needed for the `init(...)` function.

Note also, that you are doing some code-style things "wrong". Your try/catch code should be using the more modern try-with-resources mechanism, and there's no need to declare the `byte[]` array outside the try block.

So, reducing it all down to a single method, with improved code style, it would be:

```
private static byte[] doCrypto(int cipherMode,  Key key, byte[] inputBytes) 
          throws CryptoException {

    try (Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")) {
        cipher.init(cipherMode, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | InvalidKeyException
            | BadPaddingException
            | IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
        throw new CryptoException("Error doCrypto", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll read a bit on "try-with-resources mechanism".
Thanks a lot for your advices, I'll remember them! ;)